# hasMany foreignKey not working in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have some models - kanban_cards, kanban_checklists, kanban_checkitems.

kanban_cards model:

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('kanban_card', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    label: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    listId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ...
  })
}
```

kanban_checklist:

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('kanban_checklist', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    cardId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  })
}
```

And the association is:

```
const models = {
  KanbanCards: KanbanCards(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
  KanbanChecklists: KanbanChecklists(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes),
  ...
}
...
models.KanbanCards.hasMany(models.KanbanChecklists, { as: 'checklists', foreignKey: 'cardId' })
models.KanbanChecklists.belongsTo(models.KanbanCards)
```

It works fine if I use `findAll`, but if I try to create, it doesn't work.

It says.
column "kanbanCardId" of relation "kanban_checklists" does not exist

I am going to use `cardId` rather than `kanbanCardId`.

I tried to set references to `cardId`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indicated an explicit foreign key column in `hasMany` you should do the same for the other part - `belongsTo`:

```
models.KanbanChecklists.belongsTo(models.KanbanCards, { foreignKey: 'cardId' })
```

Otherwise Sequelize generate a foreign key name itself like in your case `kanbanCard`+`id`:

> The name of the foreign key in the join table (representing the target model) or an object representing the type definition for the other column (see Sequelize.define for syntax). When using an object, you can add a name property to set the name of the column. Defaults to the name of target + primary key of target

Comment: Thanks. How to figure this out using references? What did I do wrong?

Comment: You mean to find wrong foreign keys in DB and create the correct ones?

Comment: I want to set another foreign key, don't want auto generated foreign key like `kanbanCardId` using `references`. Like this. `cardId: { type: DataTypes.UUID,    allowNull: false, references: { model: 'kanbanCard', key: 'id', }}`

Comment: Usually I use `references` option only in migrations to be able to create a proper foreign key in DB